# How to test JavaScript's Intl.NumberFormat()

Tags: javascript, internationalization

The goal is to provide international visitors with a good user experience (the website is in the US). The site uses JavaScript to create reports heavy in numeric content and I would like users to see the data formatted using their local conventions. Thus I'm prototyping using `Intl.NumberFormat()`.

I had assumed I would be able to test how users from different locations would experience the site by changing my Windows 10's regional and language settings since [MDN documents Intl.NumberFormat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) :

> In basic use without specifying a locale, a formatted string in the default locale and with default options is returned.

However, when I changed my settings to Germany and German, the `resolvedOptions()` still returns a `locale` value of 'en-US', and the test number is still formatted using US conventions.

**Q1: Why 'en-US' and not 'de-DE'? What am I misunderstanding?**

**Q2: How can I test as if I were an international user?**

This is how I'm formatting the number and getting the value of the object's `locale`:

```js
let n = '12345678.99';
let f = new Intl.NumberFormat();
let options = f.resolvedOptions();
console.log('locale = ', options.locale, '\t', 'n = ', f.format(n));
```

Edited. Removed Q3.

[JSFiddle to test new NumberFormat()](https://jsfiddle.net/taa1953/pb5tzg4m/1/)

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a question asking for many unique answers. I'd be happy to supply an answer, but I'm concerned that this question could be off-topic.

Comment: The browser itself should have a locale set. Some browsers (like IE) would use the system locale, but I don't think Firefox does.

Comment: _"would you please go to this fiddle and copy/paste your results in an answer"_ Stackoverflow is not the proper place for asking this and an improper use of the answers section. Note your browser maybe defaulting to the locale that was set during install and not looking up the current  OS locale. Change the browsers language options to see if that changes your outcome

Comment: The [specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/6.0/index.html#sec-defaultlocale) defines the default locale as "the host environment's current locale". This and many other topics in that specification are intentionally vague or explicitly "implementation dependant". The default locale might or might not be based on the browser language, browser preferred language(s), OS language, OS locale settings, or other preferences. Posting your location and browser is really not helpful to answer your question. Having a look at the actual implementation in browsers would be more helpful.

Comment: @VLAZ @PatrickEvans @str - I see. I had taken MDN's documentation to mean that locale is determined only from the user's regional settings. In the case of Chrome, when I changed the language setting to German then the `locale` returned is 'de'.  If anyone cares to post that as the answer and possibly elaborate, I'll accept it.